# change filenames in lists of files: slow script

Tags: bash, shell, echo, cat

I want to change the name of the files stored in a series of filelists.
This is the code I am using:

```
suffix=[event]

for i in {0..9} a b; do
    for file in $(cat gsc"${i}".list); do
        echo $file$suffix
    done
done
```

The output is fine, but the process is much slower than if I just output `$file`.
That is to say, the scripts works fine, but why so slow?

EDIT: probably not clear: I need to change the filename WITHIN the filelist (text file).

Comment: What makes you think that `echo`ing an additional variable would make the script _significantly slower_?

Comment: I do not think, it is a fact. I don't know the reason, this is what I am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Superfast and complete:

```
for i in {0..9} a b; do
    sed -i.bak "s|evt|evt[events]|g" gsc"${i}".list
done
```

It can be improved (generalized) if the specific string in the sed can be substituted by a general string. I can't do it without avoiding slowness and confusion in the task.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
suffix=[event]
cat gsc[0-9ab].list|sed "s/$/$suffix/"
```

If you need change the filename which list in gsc*.list file, try this:

```
suffix=[event]
cat gsc[0-9ab].list |while read file
do
  mv "${file}" ${file}$suffix
done
```

Comment: Or you could `sed "s|.*|mv '&' '&[event]'|" gsc[0-9ab].list | sh`

Comment: @BMW: I actually do NOT know how to change the filename WITHIN the list

Answer (score 1):

If the lists are large, needlessly expanding them in the backticks could be slowing you down, and have [additional problems](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks). Try this instead:

```
suffix='[event]'

for i in {0..9} a b; do
    while read file; do
        echo $file$suffix
    done <gsc"${i}".list
done
```

Comment: Still slow, but thanks a lot for the explanation and the link.

Answer (score 1):

`[event]` is a shell pattern. When you expand `$file$suffix`, your shell attempts to match any files in the current directory whose names match the value of `$file` followed by `e`, `v`, `n`, or `t`. Quoting the expansion should speed things up, by avoiding the attempt to match the pattern. (Note that you would get very different output if there *were* any matching files.)

```
suffix=[event]

for i in {0..9} a b; do
    for file in $(cat gsc"${i}".list); do
        echo "$file$suffix"
    done
done
```

As others have mentioned, the loop is better written

```
for i in {0..9} a b; do
    while read file; do
        echo "$file$suffix"
    done < gsc"$i".list
done
```

or replaced altogether with tripleee's `sed` command

```
sed "s|.*|mv '&' '&[event]'|" gsc[0-9ab].list | sh
```

Comment: Thanks chepner. Please can you spend a couple of words on what the sed does in this case? So I can manipulate it as I want.

Comment: The pipe character is used to separate the search text (`.*`, essentially everything) from the replacement text (`mv '&' '&[event]', with `&` being replaced by the matched search text). It creates a valid `mv` command for each line in one of the input files. For example, if `sed` reads "xyz", it outputs a line `mv 'xyz' 'xyz[event]`. The single quotes ensure that the arguments are properly quoted when the commands are parsed by `sh`.